# Why Svelte component updated variable, where in reality it didn't changed?

Tags: svelte

The listener for `state` variable in `App` component, will print two messages, as if the `state` variable has been changed.

But in reality the `state` didn't changed, and the listener should be called only once, printing message only once.

By listener I mean reactive block of code with console printing.

```svelte
$: { i += 1; console.log(i, state) }
```

Why Svelte calls listener twice? And how to avoid it? It seems like it's somehow related to `bind`.

[demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/3320557e7d434dc48bff8ef2c6fec153?version=3.38.2)

App.svelte

```svelte
<script>
    import Some from "./Some.svelte"
    let state = { v: 0 }
    
    let i = 0
    $: { i += 1; console.log(i, state) }
</script>

<Some bind:state={state}/>
```

Some.svelte

```svelte
<script>
    export let state
</script>

<div>
    v = {state.v}
</div>
```

Console output

```
1 Object { v: 0 }
2 Object { v: 0 }
```

Comment: I do not quite understand you issue? Your title and question even seem to contradict themselves.

Comment: @NicoBleiler Thanks for feedback, I updated the question, can you please take look again?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open GitHub issue "Binding in slotted compoment triggers reactive statements twice #5720" which seems to be exactly your issue.
https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5720

If you change state to an integer instead of an object it also only triggers once and is still reactive.